# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: undefined symbol: Test

Tags: java, c++, linux, jna, shared-objects

I am trying to write a custom linux library(*.so) and I stuck already at the basics.
I would like to use this library via JNA. The problem is that when Eclipse is trying to run the method `Test()` this error-message appears `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Error looking up function 'Test': /path/to/libexports.so undefined symbol: Test`

Here is the lib code:

```
#ifdef EXPORTS
    #define NATIVE_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
    #define NATIVE_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

extern "C" {
    NATIVE_API int __stdcall Test(){
        cout << "hello!";
    }
}
```

This is the Java code:

```
public interface IJnaTest extends StdCallLibrary{
    IJnaTest instance = (IJnaTest) Native.loadLibrary("exports",     IJnaTest.class);
    public int Test();
}
```

The call in the main:

```
IJnaTest.instance.Test()
```

Can anybody tell me why this is not working?

Regards Wurmi

Answer (score 0):

Ahh. I found it!

I had to extend the interface just from Library not from StdCallLibrary.